# webpackのaliasに付く$の意味

Tags: javascript, webpack

vue.jsのwebpackテンプレートのwebpackのaliasの記述に

[vuejs-templates/webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L27)

```
'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
```

と、$が付いてますがこの意味ってなんでしょうか？
aliasの名前がvue$になるわけでもないようですし。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ドキュメントにちゃんと書いてありました。
他のファイルを読み込みたい場合もalias使えるようですね。
自己解決しました。失礼しました。

http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias